# RxJS v5.x Observables wait for the first, map the result and pass to the second?

Tags: rxjs, observable, rxjs5

I'm learning RxJS and, coming from a synchronous world, it's hard. Anyways I'm trying to do simple stuff, that is combining them.

- `login` is the first `Observable<any>`: if it completes, I want to **map** the result (simply the the token property):

  `const login = this.userService.login({ username: username, password: password });`

Getting the token seems easy: `login.pipe(map(res => res.token));`

- `storage` is the second `Obsevable<boolean>`: it should take the `token` above and should return it's value (Observable, again)

  `const store = this.localStorage.setItem('token', token);`

How do I "pass" the `login` (mapped) result to the `store` (and make `store` wait for it)?

**Attempt 1**, don't know if the second waits until the first completes:

```
return this.userService.login({username: username, password: password})
  .pipe(
    map(res => res.token),
    mergeMap(token => this.localStorage.setItem(AUTH_TOKEN_KEY, token)),
    tap(res => console.log(res)) // boolean true
  );
```

Comment: I think it should wait for it. but you can change mergemap to 'tap' since localstorage.setItem is a blocking operation and return void.

Comment: @FanCheung in this case is a wrapper for localstorage (npm it), it returns an obervable.

Comment: then i don't think there's problem with your code